# How to color scatter markers as a function of a third variable

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I want to make a scatterplot (using matplotlib) where the points are shaded according to a third variable. I've got very close with this:

```
plt.scatter(w, M, c=p, marker='s')
```

where w and M are the data points and p is the variable I want to shade with respect to.
However I want to do it in greyscale rather than colour. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 214):

There's no need to manually set the colors. Instead, specify a grayscale colormap...

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Generate data...
x = np.random.random(10)
y = np.random.random(10)

# Plot...
plt.scatter(x, y, c=y, s=500) # s is a size of marker 
plt.gray()

plt.show()
```

[image]

Or, if you'd prefer a [wider range of colormaps](http://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html), you can also specify the `cmap` kwarg to `scatter`.  To use the reversed version of any of these, just specify the "`_r`" version of any of them. E.g. `gray_r` instead of `gray`.  There are several different grayscale colormaps pre-made (e.g. `gray`, `gist_yarg`, `binary`, etc).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Generate data...
x = np.random.random(10)
y = np.random.random(10)

plt.scatter(x, y, c=y, s=500, cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there anyway to draw contours round these points containing a certain amount of the total weight?

Comment: `mpl.cm` is also available directly as `plt.cm`.

Comment: @Thomas Collet: If you want to draw contours, you'd have to interpolate the data form the points to a 2D matrix, then plot that using `plt.contour()` or `plt.contourf()` -- but that's a different question

Comment: How can you add the label in the legend? In this case with continuous numbers, I suspect you would use the colorbar. What about in the case of discrete values? e.g. could I add 3 labels in the legend for my three categories?

Answer (score 33):

In matplotlib grey colors can be given as a string of a numerical value between 0-1.
For example `c = '0.1'`

Then you can convert your third variable in a value inside this range and to use it to color your points.
In the following example I used the y position of the point as the value that determines the color:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
y = [125, 32, 54, 253, 67, 87, 233, 56, 67]

color = [str(item/255.) for item in y]

plt.scatter(x, y, s=500, c=color)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: For the record, you can apply ALPHA as a colormap if you provide an (n,4) shaped array as `c` argument, with alpha values in the fourth column. If third variable is Z, with `shape=(n,1)`, then  `colors = numpy.hstack((numpy.zeros_like(z), numpy.zeros_like(z), numpy.ones_like(z), z/z.max()))` gives a very nice effect (of course it can be tweaked).

Comment: I get an error: 'length of rgba sequence should be either 3 or 4'

Comment: @MattClimbs I suspect you are calling plt.plot rather than plt.scatter as in the example.

Comment: how do you add a colorbar to this plot?

Comment: @CF84 you may want to make this a new question

Comment: @FaCoffee `plt.colorbar()` will do that

Answer (score 17):

Sometimes you may need to **plot color precisely based on the x-value case**. For example, you may have a dataframe with 3 types of variables and some data points. And you want to do following,

- Plot points corresponding to Physical variable 'A' in RED.
- Plot points corresponding to Physical variable 'B' in BLUE.
- Plot points corresponding to Physical variable 'C' in GREEN.

In this case, you may have to write to short function to map the x-values to corresponding color names as a list and then pass on that list to the `plt.scatter` command.

```
x=['A','B','B','C','A','B']
y=[15,30,25,18,22,13]

# Function to map the colors as a list from the input list of x variables
def pltcolor(lst):
    cols=[]
    for l in lst:
        if l=='A':
            cols.append('red')
        elif l=='B':
            cols.append('blue')
        else:
            cols.append('green')
    return cols
# Create the colors list using the function above
cols=pltcolor(x)

plt.scatter(x=x,y=y,s=500,c=cols) #Pass on the list created by the function here
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

[image: Coloring scatter plot as a function of x variable]

Comment: how to create a color bar for this plot?

Comment: How to form the legend for this? I have followed the above function to map colour of my choice, but I want to create a legend corresponding to each colour

Answer (score 0):

A pretty straightforward solution is also this one:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1, figsize=(8,8)) 

p = ax.scatter(x, y, c=y, cmap='cmo.deep')
fig.colorbar(p,ax=ax,orientation='vertical',label='labelname')
```