# matplotlib scatter plot colour as function of third variable

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter

I would like to know how to make matplotlib's scatter function colour points by a third variable.

Questions
[gnuplot linecolor variable in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8945699/gnuplot-linecolor-variable-in-matplotlib) and [Matplotlib scatterplot; colour as a function of a third variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8202605/matplotlib-scatterplot-colour-as-a-function-of-a-third-variable)
posed similar queries, however, the answers to those questions don't address my issue: the use of `c=arraywhichspecifiespointcolour` in the scatter function only sets the fill colour, not the edge colour. This means that the use of `c=arr...` fails when using `markersymbol='+'`, for instance (because that marker has no fill, only edges). I want points to be coloured by a third variable reliably, regardless of which symbol is used.

Is there a way to achieve this with Matplotlib's scatter function?

Comment: I get colored `+` symbols when i set `marker='+'`.

Comment: @Avaris: Works for me, too. I updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 35):

This works for me, using matplotlib 1.1:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(10)
y = np.sin(x)

plt.scatter(x, y, marker='+', s=150, linewidths=4, c=y, cmap=plt.cm.coolwarm)
plt.show()
```

Result:

[image]

Alternatively, for n points, make an array of RGB color values with shape (n, 3), and assign it to the `edgecolors` keyword argument of `scatter()`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0, 20, 100)
y = np.sin(x)
z = x + 20 * y

scaled_z = (z - z.min()) / z.ptp()
colors = plt.cm.coolwarm(scaled_z)

plt.scatter(x, y, marker='+', edgecolors=colors, s=150, linewidths=4)
plt.show()
```

Result:
[image]

That example gets the RGBA values by scaling the `z` values to the range [0,1], and calling the colormap `plt.cm.coolwarm` with the scaled values.  When called this way, a matplotlib colormap returns an array of RGBA values, with each row giving the color of the corresponding input value.  For example:

```
>>> t = np.linspace(0, 1, 5)
>>> t
array([ 0.  ,  0.25,  0.5 ,  0.75,  1.  ])
>>> plt.cm.coolwarm(t) 
array([[ 0.2298,  0.2987,  0.7537,  1.    ],
       [ 0.5543,  0.6901,  0.9955,  1.    ],
       [ 0.8674,  0.8644,  0.8626,  1.    ],
       [ 0.9567,  0.598 ,  0.4773,  1.    ],
       [ 0.7057,  0.0156,  0.1502,  1.    ]])
```

Comment: Thanks Warren for your answer. Unfortunately, your first example results in black pluses for me. I don't know why. mpl.__version__ gives 1.0.1, if that's relevant. I might have to try passing 'edgecolors' a list of rgbs, but that means I have to create those from the 'z' values and the colourmap manually, right?

Comment: I'm using version 1.1.  There were some changes to the marker code between 1.0 and 1.1, so that could be problem.  I've updated the second example to show one way of mapping 'z' values to colors (but I haven't tried that in matplotlib 1.0).

Comment: Hi Warren. Just to follow up on this, when I use a newer (1.1) version  of matplotlib, I do indeed get coloured points with exactly the same code. Issue considered solved. Thanks!

Comment: If you are using `Python 2.7` remember to use: `from __future__ import division` or the `colors` array will be all zeroes (due to rounding down)