# Matplotlib: how to plot colored points without looping?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have a numpy matrix of 2d points that I am plotting, which I can do like this:

```
xs = np.array([[0,0], [1,0], [2,2]])

for x in xs:
    plt.plot(x[0], x[1], 'o', color="red")
```

Or, without looping I can just do:

```
xs = np.array([[0,0], [1,0], [2,2]])
plt.plot(xs[:,0], xs[:,1], 'o', color="red")
```

Now suppose I also have an array of corresponding colors:
    clrs = [0, 1, 0]
    mycolors = ['red', 'black']

So `0` is associated with `red` and `1` is associated with `black`. I can plot the colored points in a loop using:

```
xs = np.array([[0,0], [1,0], [2,2]])
clrs = [0, 1, 0]
mycolors = ['red', 'black']

for x,c in zip(xs,clrs):
    plt.plot(x[0], x[1], 'o', color=mycolors[c])
```

How can I do this without the loop?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12965075/matplotlib-scatter-plot-colour-as-function-of-third-variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `plt.scatter`, and specify a color vector:

```
plt.scatter(xs[:,0], xs[:,1], c=list('rk')) #r is red, k is black
```

[image]