# Color every point in a scatterplot differently in numpy/python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, colors

I am solving an optimization problem. There are n iterations and at each one I have a point x_n=[x_n1, x_n2]. I want to plot the iterates x_n so that as n increases the color of the points gets dark or lighter or whatever. Currently I can plot the iterates but they are all the same color so i cannot tell which points correspond to higher values of n.

The variable x_test is an array which contains all the iterates from x_0 to x_n. Here is my code to plot it:

```
pl.scatter(x_test[:,0], x_test[:,1])
pl.show()
```

I have found a lot of info on how to color graphs but not in the way I am desiring, where each point corresponds to a different light/darkness.

Here is a minimal, complete, verifiable example:

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl
x = np.array([[1,1],[1,2],[1,3],[2,4]])
pl.plot(x[:,0], x[:,1])
```

This gives the scatter plot of the points in the array x but I need them to each be a different color corresponding to the position in x, i.e. [1,1] should be the lightest, then [1,2] will be slightly dark, etc until [2,4] is the darkest.

edit: here is the solution I went with:

```
scaled_itera = np.array(range(x_test.shape[0]))/(float(x_test.shape[0])-1)
colors = pl.cm.coolwarm(scaled_itera)

pl.scatter(x_test[:,0], x_test[:,1], color=colors)
pl.show()
```

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12965075/matplotlib-scatter-plot-colour-as-function-of-third-variable/12965761

Comment: Thanks @WarrenWeckesser, that did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly give a list of color to `plt.scatter()`. For example: you can do:

```
import seaborn as sns
color_list = sns.color_palette("Paired", n_colors=x_test.shape[0])
plt.scatter(x_test[:,0], x_test[:,1], color=color_list)
```

Check [colormap_reference](https://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html) if you want to stay with `matplotlib` for colors.

An example using `plt.cm`:

```
plt.scatter(x_test[:,0], x_test[:,1], color=plt.cm.Paired.colors[:x_test.shape[0]])
```

Comment: I think `color` also takes scalar values and applies a palette internally. No need for seaborn then :)

Comment: I don't have this module seaborn, I would prefer to stay within the confines of numpy/pylab

Comment: You do not need to use `seaborn` or `palettable`. You can directly use a list of colors but I just like them because they provide predefined palettes. See the link in my updated answer there.

Comment: Okay it's not clear to me how to do it without seaborn/palettable. I can deduce that I will use, for example, cmap = 'autumn' but what should be the entry for color = ?

Comment: Check the link I posted in the answer above to use the color maps in `matplotlib`.

Comment: Yeah it's not helpful to me, they plot all of them at once and it's hard for me to see what's going on. I figured it out using the comment on the question anyways, I will post my solution.

Comment: It's straightforward. See my edited answer.

Answer (score -1):

you need to loop through each point

assuming your data are something like

```
x = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8]]
```

then, something like

```
c_aray = ['black','green','red','blue']
for i in range(len(x)):
    xn = x[i]
    plt.plot(xn[0],xn[1],color = c_aray[i],'o')
```

Comment: This I can do but I have thousands of iterates so i will need a way for the color list, c_aray, to be generated automatically

Comment: thousands might be hard, but dozens is possible; start with a hexadecimal code, and increment it "smartly".  this will get you off in the right direction: https://www.thedataschool.co.uk/gwilym-lockwood/viridis-colours-tableau/

Comment: In fact there is an easier way than to loop over all the points, I edited the solution into the question.