# What is the most descriptive way to plot Lorenz System?

Tags: python, matplotlib, mplot3d, lorenz-system

I am (numerically) solving the Lorenz System by using different methods. I am plotting it using matplotlib but I would like a way to distinguish better the points.

For example:

Let's assume the points to be plotted are stored in the array `a` which has the form

```
array([[  0.5       ,   0.5       ,   0.5       ],
       [  0.50640425,   0.6324552 ,   0.48965064]])
         #...
```

Now these lines of code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot(a[:,0],a[:,1],a[:,2])
plt.show()
```

produce:

[image]

Not very descriptive, is it? So I thought plotting discrete points would work better. So these ones:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.scatter(a[:,0],a[:,1],a[:,2], s=0.2)
plt.show()
```

produce:

[image]

But it is not as descriptive as I want. I want to know what is the most descriptive way to plot the Lorenz system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider making your scatter points transparent. You can do this by passing an `alpha` keyword to `plt.scatter`. Here's an example, modified from `mplot3d` [example gallery](http://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/lorenz_attractor.html), with `alpha = 1.0`, which is the default value:

```
ax.scatter(xs, ys, zs, alpha=1.0, s=0.2)
```

[image: opaque]

And here is the same scatter point cloud drawn with `alpha = 0.1`:

```
ax.scatter(xs, ys, zs, alpha=0.1, s=0.2)
```

[image: transparent]

Note that while this appears to be a good visualization, the interactive part of it is quite slow for a large number of points. If you really need fast performance, consider an alternative approach - splitting the lines in segments and coloring them by index, similarly to what's being done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18516488/4118756).