# matplotlib: plotting a 2d array

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

So I've been going round in circles on this for the last day, and hoping someone can put me out of my misery.

I have a function f that depends on x and y values and when plotting f against y, gives the following [figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AI5pY.png).

Now each of the lines are for a value of x [0,1] and I feel there must be a way to colour/contour the plot such that it can easily be identified which line corresponds to what value of x. I've tried numerous searches, but have not found anything that helps in this instance.

The code to reproduce the data that gives my figure is as below. Any help  would be great, as I feel I'm missing something glaringly obvious here.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y = np.linspace(0,100)
x = np.linspace(0,1,11)

f = np.zeros(( len(y), len(x) ))


for j in range(len(x)):
    i=0
    for r in y:
        f[i,j] = (1000 + (-r * 2)) + (1000*(1-x[j]))
        i += 1

 plt.plot(f, y)
```

Comment: What about a [legend](http://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16992038/inline-labels-in-matplotlib and http://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html

Comment: Or plotting in [3D](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html), or [annotations](http://matplotlib.org/users/annotations_intro.html), or [colormapping the lines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8945699/gnuplot-linecolor-variable-in-matplotlib/18516488#18516488), or if you have only a very limited number of x values use a different [linestyle](http://matplotlib.org/api/lines_api.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D.set_linestyle) for each.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y = np.linspace(0, 100)
x = np.linspace(0, 1, 11)
f = np.zeros((len(y), len(x)))

for j in range(len(x)):
    i = 0
    for r in y:
        f[i, j] = (1000 + (-r * 2)) + (1000 * (1 - x[j]))
        i += 1

plt.plot(f, y)
labels = [f[xs, 0] for xs in x]
plt.legend(labels, loc='best')
plt.show()
```

Just fix the labels

Comment: Sorry I probably should have mentioned in the original post that I didn't want to use a legend, as I have another similar function that would be plotted together and the legend gets out of hand quickly. Thanks for the response though.

Answer (score 0):

I gave a few possibilities in my comment:

> Or plotting in
>   [3D](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html), or
>   [annotations](http://matplotlib.org/users/annotations_intro.html), or
>   [colormapping the
>   lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8945699/gnuplot-linecolor-variable-in-matplotlib/18516488#18516488),
>   or if you have only a very limited number of x values use a different
>   [linestyle](http://matplotlib.org/api/lines_api.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D.set_linestyle)
>   for each.

Beside that you can create a new axis specifically for **x**. In the following snippet adapted from your code I put the **x** value in the top horizontal axis:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y = np.linspace(0,100)
x = np.linspace(0,1,11)

f = np.zeros(( len(y), len(x) ))


for j in range(len(x)):
    i=0
    for r in y:
        f[i,j] = (1000 + (-r * 2)) + (1000*(1-x[j]))
        i += 1

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax2 = ax1.twiny()
ax2.set_xticks(x)
ax2.set_xticklabels(["%.3f" % xi for xi in x])
ax1.plot(f, y)
```

The result is the following:

[image: Double x axis]

Comment: Thanks for the linked examples, they're quite helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Since the lines correspond to more or less continuous values of x, I would color the lines according to a colormap.
Then use a `colorbar` to show the mapping of `x` to colors.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cmx
import matplotlib.colors as colors

y = np.linspace(0,100)
x = np.linspace(0,1,11)

f = np.zeros(( len(y), len(x) ))


for j in range(len(x)):
    i=0
    for r in y:
        f[i,j] = (1000 + (-r * 2)) + (1000*(1-x[j]))
        i += 1


cn  = colors.Normalize(vmin=0, vmax=1)
scalar_map = cmx.ScalarMappable(norm=cn, cmap='jet')
# see plt.colormaps() for many more colormaps

for f_, x_ in zip(f.T, x):
    c = scalar_map.to_rgba(x_)
    plt.plot(f_, y, color=c)

scalar_map.set_array([])  # dunno why we need this. plt.colorbar fails otherwise.
plt.colorbar(scalar_map, label='x')
```

[image]