# plot x-y plot of words which match across two lists (string version of plt.scatter)

Tags: python, string, list, intersection, scatter

I don't really know how to start with this at all. I have two lists of strings:

```
['a','b','c','d']
['a','c','g','e','f']
```

I would like to make a plot (using imshow perhaps) of the two lists of words, one on each axis with a heatmap showing how often those words appear in both lists. Ideally, this would be sorted such that the most matching words appear in one section of the heatmap, but this isn't essential. It is the equivelent of:

[Matplotlib scatterplot; colour as a function of a third variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8202605/matplotlib-scatterplot-colour-as-a-function-of-a-third-variable)

but for strings in two lists with a colorbar showing how often they appear. Thanks!