# Matplotlib Python Scatter Plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I want to plot up a data set of dimension 50*50. Each datum is associated with a "probability", a number between 0 and 1. I want to represent their probability by color gradation. I know how to plot up the dots using matplotlib tool. But how should I associate them with the appropriate colors?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried?  Have you read the [docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.scatter)?  What about them didn't you understand or is not working as you expect?

Comment: to confirm you want to plot 2500 dimensions in a 2d space? ...

Comment: repeat? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8202605/matplotlib-scatterplot-colour-as-a-function-of-a-third-variable

Comment: and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17865240/plotting-clustered-data-in-matplotlib which was just asked.

Answer (score 8):

You need to use a colormap to associate a certain color to each point. For example consider the following piece of code

```
 import numpy as np
 from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 import random as ran

 fig = plt.figure()
 ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

 cmhot = plt.cm.get_cmap("hot")
 xs =  [ran.random()*50 for n in range(0,50)]
 ys = [ran.random()*50 for n in range(0,50)]
 zs = [ran.random() for n in range(0,50)]
 l = ax.scatter(xs, ys, zs, c=zs, cmap=cmhot)
 fig.colorbar(l)
 plt.show()
```

That results in this:

[image: Scatter 3d plot]

In this case the color is associated to the z value, by using the default "hot" colormap.

Answer (score 6):

Something like this? The key point is `c=z` which tells `scatter` to apply the colormap specified with `cmap` to each point according to the scalar value of `z`.

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x=numpy.random.randint(0,100,size=25)
y=numpy.random.randint(0,100,size=25)
z=numpy.random.rand(25)
plt.scatter(x, y, c=z, s=100, cmap=plt.cm.cool, edgecolors='None', alpha=0.75)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

[image]

You can also give a list of colors as the `c` argument. For example

```
colors=[(1,0,1,el) for el in z]
plt.scatter(x, y, c=colors, s=100, edgecolors='None')
```

In this case each point has a RGB tuple associated with it and `scatter` uses the color you specify. With the two lines given above you'd have the alpha value of each point vary according to the probability `z`. This you can not achieve with just the `alpha` keyword of `scatter`:

[image]