# Plotting data points in each iteration of a clustering algorithm

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have written a clustering algorithm, now I need to visualize cluster assignments in each iteration of the algorithm. To be specific, I need to generate random colors based on the number of the clusters that is determined by the user at first and assign each cluster a color and plot data points in each iteration based on the cluster they belong to. How Should I do that? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SU! To improve potential answers please state what you tried to far.

Comment: this might help http://stackoverflow.com/a/8204981/2530083

Comment: Thanks. It was helpful but I need to animate it.I have put plt.draw()
  and time.sleep(1) in each iteration but I still see the last iteration's assignment