# How to make a scatter plot for clustering in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, python-ggplot

I am carrying out clustering and try to plot the result. A dummy data set is :

*data*

```
import numpy as np

X = np.random.randn(10)
Y = np.random.randn(10)
Cluster = np.array([0, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 3, 0, 2])    # Labels of cluster 0 to 3
```

*cluster center*

```
 centers = np.random.randn(4, 2)    # 4 centers, each center is a 2D point
```

---

### Question

I want to make a scatter plot to show the points in `data` and color the points based on the cluster labels.

Then I want to superimpose the `center` points on the same scatter plot, in another shape (e.g. 'X') and a fifth color (as there are 4 clusters).

---

### Comment

- I turned to **seaborn** 0.6.0 but found no API to accomplish the task.
- **ggplot** by yhat could made the scatter plot nice but the second plot would replace the first one.
- I got confused by the `color` and `cmap` in **matplotlib** so I wonder if I could use seaborn or ggplot to do it.

Comment: Could be more specific on `Then I want to superimpose the center points on the same scatter plot, in another shape (e.g. 'X') and a fifth color (as there are 4 clusters).`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The first part of your question can be done using `colorbar` and specifying the colours to be the `Cluster` array. I have vaguely understood the second part of your question, but I believe this is what you are looking for.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.random.randn(10)
y = np.random.randn(10)
Cluster = np.array([0, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 3, 0, 2])    # Labels of cluster 0 to 3
centers = np.random.randn(4, 2) 

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
scatter = ax.scatter(x,y,c=Cluster,s=50)
for i,j in centers:
    ax.scatter(i,j,s=50,c='red',marker='+')
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
plt.colorbar(scatter)

fig.show()
```

which results in:

[image]

wherein your "centres" have been shown using `+` marker. You can specify any colours you want to them in the same way have done for `x and y`

Comment: Thank you very much. I think I should read through the documentation of matplotlib.

Answer (score 2):

Part of this has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8204981/841567). The outline is

```
plt.scatter(x, y, c=color)
```

Quoting the documentation of [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.scatter):

> c : color or sequence of color, optional, default
>   [...]
>   Note that c should not be a single numeric RGB or RGBA sequence because that is indistinguishable from an array of values to be colormapped. c can be a 2-D array in which the rows are RGB or RGBA, however.

So in your case, you need a color for each cluster and than fill the color array according to the cluster assignment of each point.

```
red = [1, 0, 0]
green = [0, 1, 0]
blue = [0, 0, 1]
colors = [red, red, green, blue, green]
```