# Is there a simple way to draw contour or surface maps from 3 columns in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

didn"t find an answer to that.

my data looks like that:

```
import pandas as pd    
mapDF = pd.DataFrame({u'N1': {0: 20,  1: 20,  2: 20,  3: 20,  4: 20,  5: 21,  6: 21,  7: 21,  8: 21,  9: 21,  10: 22,  11: 22,  12: 22,  13: 22,  14: 22,  15: 23,  16: 23,  17: 23,  18: 23,  19: 23,  20: 24,  21: 24,  22: 24,  23: 24,  24: 24}, 
    u'N2': {0: 50,  1: 51,  2: 52,  3: 53,  4: 54,  5: 50,  6: 51,  7: 52,  8: 53,  9: 54,  10: 50,  11: 51,  12: 52,  13: 53,  14: 54,  15: 50,  16: 51,  17: 52,  18: 53,  19: 54,  20: 50,  21: 51,  22: 52,  23: 53,  24: 54}, 
    u'optGain': {0: 1.119175,  1: 1.11189,  2: 1.0984430000000001,  3: 1.0648280000000001,  4: 1.0459499999999999,  5: 1.149848,  6: 1.154882,  7: 1.1460840000000001,  8: 1.096886,  9: 1.098012,  10: 1.1416869999999999,  11: 1.118763,  12: 1.118763,  13: 1.098276,  14: 1.068576,  15: 1.1165069999999999,  16: 1.128744,  17: 1.128744,  18: 1.1070770000000001,  19: 1.0678430000000001,  20: 1.100743,  21: 1.096325,  22: 1.087421,  23: 1.090177,  24: 1.089968}, 
    u'simGain': {0: 0.94936399999999999,  1: 0.94052000000000002,  2: 0.93819300000000005,  3: 0.90808299999999997,  4: 0.91296299999999997,  5: 0.94936399999999999,  6: 0.90771599999999997,  7: 0.90771599999999997,  8: 0.91296299999999997,  9: 0.85592699999999999,  10: 0.90232000000000001,  11: 0.90232000000000001,  12: 0.84629200000000004,  13: 0.75560000000000005,  14: 0.75560000000000005,  15: 0.92555200000000004,  16: 0.87239299999999997,  17: 0.87274600000000002,  18: 0.88428399999999996,  19: 0.83454799999999996,  20: 0.86954900000000002,  21: 0.88426899999999997,  22: 0.88746899999999995,  23: 0.82285200000000003,  24: 0.82285200000000003}})
```

and I am trying to make a contour map or surface plot where N1 ,  N2 are the x, y axis and optGain column is the value.
tried with pylab or plotlib but none takes in the DF and all require meshing the data. This is cumbersome since I am not looking to plot a function but rather an already existing data.
any help or pointers will be appreciated
Thanks!

Comment: Please don't post screenshots; instead, try to post things that can be copy-pasted. Thanks.

Comment: tried it - but it pasted all mixed up. anyway - added it . thanks for your input.

Comment: Matplotlib always plot data, not functions.

Comment: Try `matplotlab.pyplot.tricontour`.

Comment: tricontour looks like what i needed - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8202605/matplotlib-scatterplot-colour-as-a-function-of-a-third-variable).

In general, you could do this with

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.scatter(mapDF.N1.values, mapDF.N2.values, c=mapDF.optGain.values, s=500)
plt.gray()

plt.show()
```

It will draw things in a continuous greys cale of the values.

---

**Edit**

The above will draw a grey scale scatter plot. As Syrtis Major notes in the comments, try [`tricontour`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html) for a 2d contour plot. With this function, note the `colors` parameter, specifically:

> If a tuple of matplotlib color args (string, float, rgb, etc), different levels will be plotted in different colors in the order specified.

So you can use your `mapDF.optGain.values` to build RGB colors for different levels.

Comment: Thanks - though it's not a colormap, so i cannot see the values and with large datasets it will be hard to work with.

Comment: Can you post a link to something that is a colormap? The terminology might be different.

Comment: OK - i think the correct term is a surface plot - but I wish to look at it as a 2D contour with colors (like topographic maps). I will rephrase the question - thanks again

Comment: @Shuki See update. If you need further clarifications, feel free to comment.