# Assign color to points (x,y)

Tags: python, plot, colors

I have a list of points (r1,r2) which I am plotting. For these points I have a certain error value 's' associated with each one of them. I want to assign a color with respect to what the error for each point is. For example red for highest error and blue for lowest error and also get a legend showing the range of colors. Can it be done? I have the following piece of code that I am trying:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

data = scatter(r1, r2, c=s)

ax.set_title('Colormap for errors')
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Matplotlib scatterplot; colour as a function of a third variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8202605/matplotlib-scatterplot-colour-as-a-function-of-a-third-variable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this,

[image]

---

The source code is as follows. Refer to [colormaps](http://matplotlib.org/users/colormaps.html) for more about colormaps.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.random.rand(100)
y = np.random.rand(100)

plt.scatter(x, y, c=x, cmap='bwr')
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

Comment: This works just perfect. I have a follow up though, the value of 'c' here is normalized with respect to the maximum value of 'x'?