# How to plot a third variable as color on a hexbin in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Let's use the famous Titanic dataset found here:

http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/wiki/pub/Main/DataSets/titanic3.xls

And read it in as a dataframe: `df`

I'm interested in visualizing survival rate per passenger segment, with passenger segments defined as a hexbin bucket of `fare` x `age`.

Generating the hexbin of those two features is fairly straightforward:

```
sns.set(font_scale=1.5)
sns.set_style("white")

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))

fig = sns.jointplot("age", "fare", data=df, kind="hex",
             joint_kws={'gridsize':22},
             xlim=(-20, 90), ylim=(-20,300), mincnt=0,
             stat_func=None, marginal_kws={"bins":10, "color":"k", "rug":True}, color="black" 
          )
```

[image: hexbin]

But rather than density (which is shown in the marginal plot anyway), I'd like the color of the chart to represent survival rate (`survived` is a binary 1 & 0 dataframe feature) for all passengers counted within each bin.

Answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8202605/896802) are somewhat helpful, but scatter plots are problematic for dense datasets, thus my use of a hexbin.

Any help how I might make this work?

Comment: Hexbin can take anything an the `C` input (http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html?highlight=hexbin#matplotlib.axes.Axes.hexbin) but I am not sure how to convince seaborn to take a different value for it.

Comment: A non-programming issue is that this is a standard plot format, and the reason these are called "marginal distributions".  If you don't want the marginal plots to be connected to the interior plot, you should probably plot them on different axes.  Otherwise it will be hard to disentangle the usual meaning from your alternate meaning.