# Make a spectrogram of existing data in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, spectrogram

I have some data that I'd like to represent as a spectrogram or heat-map in python 2.7. At the moment, I have an array of three columns (time, channel number and flux), and thousands of rows that represent each data point. How would I be able to plot all the data points if I want time on the x axis, channel number on the y axis, and the magnitude of the flux represented by a colour?

I've looked through a fair few questions on here, plus other resources online, and haven't been able to apply any of the answers to my own situation. Ideally I'd want something [like this](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.spectrogram.html), just with frequency replaced by channel and also using my own data rather than generating something.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Matplotlib scatterplot; colour as a function of a third variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8202605/matplotlib-scatterplot-colour-as-a-function-of-a-third-variable)

Comment: Emma, a spectrogram displays the frequency content of successive chunks of a one-dimensional vector of data, which is why scipy.signal.spectrogram takes a 1D data array and generates a 2D image, time (or whatever dimension the data was in) vs frequency. As guessed in the above comment, you may want a scatter plot, or kernel density, or heatmap, but not a spectrogram.