# Color Gradient on line plot based on y value

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

A similar question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40867417/matplotlib-color-gradient-based-on-y-value). But it is concerned with the scatter plot. I want to achieve the same with simple line plot. I know there are solutions for drawing multicolored line but I'm not interested in that.

I want something like below where maxima and minima are clearly distinguishable by color:

[image: Expection]

In this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35656396/6422069) provides a very close solution however it is not generic, it works on predefined functions, does not work on dataset.

In `R` it is doable using `ggplot2` ([Source](https://community.periscopedata.com/t/k9rw2k/plotting-a-gradient-line-in-r))

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: What's wrong with scatter? If you really just don't like the name, you could always rename `plot=scatter`...

Comment: @HAL9001, I want continuous line, not just discrete points.

Comment: Might be useful (and possible duplicates): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13622909/matplotlib-how-to-colorize-a-large-number-of-line-segments-as-independent-gradi/13649811#13649811  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16051270/matplotlib-plotting-a-single-line-that-continuously-changes-color

Comment: The question I marked as duplicate encodes `x` as color. I suppose it's obvious how to use `y` instead.