# plot two interpolations of two set of points in the same plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, colors, interpolation

I have a set of points which can be "distinguished" in two parts, based on their coordinates. To make an example, imagine:

```
np.random.seed(1234)           #I hope this is how you use random seed, not sure

### First part of data ###
xcoord1 = np.random.uniform(10,20,100).reshape(-1,1)
ycoord1 = np.random.uniform(20,30, 100).reshape(-1,1)
part1 = np.hstack((xcoord1, ycoord1))
### second part of data ###
xcoord2 = np.random.uniform(60,90,100).reshape(-1,1)
ycoord2 = np.ranodom.uniform(5,25,100).reshape(-1,1)
part2 = np.vstack((xcoord2, ycoord2))
```

Important: the two part of points are totally disjoint as you can see here
[image]

**What I want to do**

I have a set of values

```
values1 = np.random.uniform(0,1, size = 200) #for part1 
values2 = np.random.uniform(0,1, size = 200) #for part2
```

each corresponding to the points in `part1` and `part2`. I can easily plot them based on the color ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45670678/matplotlib-colormap-scatter-plot-passing-a-third-variable-for-color-invalid-rg))

```
colors1 = [cmap(tl) for tl in values1]
colors2 = [cmap(tl) for tl in values2]
colors = ['yellow', 'red', 'green']
cmap = matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap(colors)
plt.scatter(part1[:,0], part1[:,1], c = colors1)
plt.scatter(part2[:,0], part2[:,1], c=colors2)
```

obtaining the following [image: image1]

Now I would like to do some interpolation on the colors, BUT I would like to have the color meshing only in the two areas where I have the points, not in between them! So I want to do two interpolations.

I managed to do the following:

```
xi = np.linspace(min(min(part1[:,0]), min(part2[:,0])), max(max(part1[:,0]), max(part2[:,0])), 200)
yi = np.linspace(min(min(part1[:,1]), min(part2[:,1])), max(max(part1[:,1]), max(part2[:,1])), 200)
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(xi, yi)
gridPoints = (xx,yy)
totalpart = np.vstack((part1, part2))
totalvalue = np.hstack((values1, values2))
zi = griddata(totalpart, totalvalue, gridPoints, method='linear')
plt.imshow(zi, origin = 'lower', cmap = cmap)
```

Which gives me

[image: image3]

Now this is an interpolation, but as you see the colors occupy the part of the plot in between the two "clusters", that used to be white. I would like to have each one of the two "clusters" (i.e. `part1` and `part2` ) to have their own interpolation (with the same colors if possible).

How can I do that?

**WHAT I WANT, DONE IN PAINT**

I tried to do in paint what I want to achieve, so you have a better idea:

[image: imagepaint]

Answer (score 1):

I would create a mask to set the values of `zi` outside the two regions to `np.nan`. That is

```
mask1 = (gridPoints[0] >= 10) & (gridPoints[0] <= 20) & \
    (gridPoints[1] >= 20) & (gridPoints[1] <= 30)
mask2 = (gridPoints[0] >= 60) & (gridPoints[0] <= 90) & \
    (gridPoints[1] >= 5) & (gridPoints[1] <= 25)
mask = mask1 | mask2

zi[~mask] = np.nan
plt.imshow(zi, origin = 'lower', cmap = cmap)
```

The result looks like this:
[image]

Comment: nice one! What you did looks great. Would there be an option to do it without having those net cuts?

Comment: Also, I don't understand what `new_zi` is

Comment: oh okay it would be `zi` ahah that was dumb. It works!

Comment: Correct! the new_zi stuff was a copy-paste typo. Great that it works!I think that, at scipy level, the only alternative way of doing that would be to interpolate the two sets independently. Then display the resulting matrices to different positions of the same figure.

Comment: "at scipy level" : so is there another method to do this type of interpolation?

Comment: also, do you know if there is a way of adding a colorbar? I know I can add normally a colorbar using `plt.colorbar()` but I am not sure how it would work ehre