# How to create a plot with a repeating color pattern?

Tags: python, matplotlib, color-scheme

For my report, I'm creating a special color plot in jupyter notebook. There are two parameters, `x` and `y`.

```
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(-1,1,0.1)
y = np.arange(1,11,1)
```

with which I compute a third quantity. Here is an example to demonstrate the concept:

```
values = []
for i in range(len(y)) :
    z = y[i] * x**3
    # in my case the value z represents phases of oscillators
    # so I will transform the computed values to the intervall [0,2pi)
    values.append(z)
values = np.array(values) % 2*np.pi
```

I'm plotting `y` vs `x`. For each `y = 1,2,3,4...` there will be a horizontal line with total length two. For example: The coordinate `(0.5,8)` stands for a single point on line 8 at position `x = 0.5` and `z(0.5,8)` is its associated value.

Now I want to represent each point on all ten lines with a unique color that is determined by `z(x,y)`. Since `z(x,y)` takes only values in `[0,2pi)` I need a color scheme that starts at zero (for example `z=0` corresponds to blue). For increasing z the color continuously changes and in the end at `2pi` it takes the same color again (so at `z ~ 2pi` it becomes blue again).

Does someone know how this can be done in python?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Matplotlib scatterplot; colour as a function of a third variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8202605/matplotlib-scatterplot-colour-as-a-function-of-a-third-variable)

Comment: Matplotlib comes with [three cyclic colormaps](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/_images/sphx_glr_colormap_reference_005.png) inbuild. If there is any problem using them please provide a [mcve],

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/gallery/index.html#color , https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/index.html#colors

Comment: Thx for the links. I dont understand how create a "symmetric" color scheme. By symmetric i mean: it has unique colors in [0,pi] and this colors are reversed in [pi,2pi] so that for example pi/2 and 3pi/2 or 0 and 2pi have the same color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The kind of structure for x, y and z you need, is easier using a `meshgrid`. Also, to have a lot of x-values between -1 and 1, `np.linspace(-1,1,N)` divides the range in N even intervals.

Using `meshgrid`, `z` can be calculated in one line using [numpy's vectorization](https://www.pythonlikeyoumeanit.com/Module3_IntroducingNumpy/VectorizedOperations.html). This runs much faster.

To set a repeating color, a [cyclic colormap](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html#cyclic) such as `hsv` can be used. There the last color is the same as the starting color.

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

x, y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-1,1,100), np.arange(1,11,1))
z = (y * x**3) % 2*np.pi
plt.scatter(x, y, c=z, s=6, cmap='hsv')
plt.yticks(range(1,11))
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

Alternatively, a symmetric colormap could be built taken the colors from and [existing map](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html) and combining them with the same colors in reverse order.

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors

colors_orig = plt.cm.viridis_r(np.linspace(0, 1, 128))
# combine the colors with the reversed array and build a new colormap
colors = np.vstack((colors_orig, colors_orig[::-1]))
symcmap = mcolors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('symcmap', colors)

x, y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-1,1,100), np.arange(1,11,1))
z = (y * x**3) % 2*np.pi
plt.scatter(x, y, c=z, s=6, cmap=symcmap)
plt.yticks(range(1,11))
plt.show()
```

Comment: That is exactly what I am looking for. Thank you!  Is there a way to substitute plt.scatter(x, y, c=z, s=6, cmap=symcmap) with another command to get lines - instead of dots. I tried plt.plot(x, y, c=z, s=6, cmap=symcmap) but it does not work...

Answer (score 0):

Multicolored lines are somewhat more complicated than just scatter plots. The [docs](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/multicolored_line.html) have an example using `LineCollection`s. Here is the adapted code. Note that the line segments are colored using their start point, so make sure there are enough x values. Also, the x and y limits aren't set automatically any more.

The code also adds a colorbar to illustrate how the colors map to the z values. Some interesting code from [Jake VanderPlas](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/04.10-customizing-ticks.html) shows how to create ticks for multiples of π.

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection

# code from Jake VanderPlas
def format_func(value, tick_number):
    # find number of multiples of pi/2
    N = int(np.round(2 * value / np.pi))
    if N == 0:
        return "0"
    elif N == 1:
        return r"$\pi/2$"
    elif N == 2:
        return r"$\pi$"
    elif N % 2 > 0:
        return r"${0}\pi/2$".format(N)
    else:
        return r"${0}\pi$".format(N // 2)

x = np.linspace(-1, 1, 500)
y_max = 10
# Create a continuous norm to map from data points to colors
norm = plt.Normalize(0, 2 * np.pi)

for y in range(1, y_max + 1):
    z = (y * x ** 3) % 2 * np.pi
    y_array = y * np.ones_like(x)
    points = np.array([x, y_array]).T.reshape(-1, 1, 2)
    segments = np.concatenate([points[:-1], points[1:]], axis=1)
    lc = LineCollection(segments, cmap='hsv', norm=norm)
    lc.set_array(z)  # Set the values used for colormapping
    lc.set_linewidth(2)
    line = plt.gca().add_collection(lc)
    # plt.scatter(x, y_array, c=z, s=10, norm=norm, cmap='hsv')

cbar = plt.colorbar(line)  # , ticks=[k*np.pi for k in np.arange(0, 2.001, 0.25)])
cbar.locator = plt.MultipleLocator(np.pi / 2)
cbar.minor_locator = plt.MultipleLocator(np.pi / 4)
cbar.formatter = plt.FuncFormatter(format_func)
cbar.ax.minorticks_on()
cbar.update_ticks()

plt.yticks(range(1, y_max + 1))  # one tick for every y
plt.xlim(x.min(), x.max())  # the LineCollection doesn't force the limits
plt.ylim(0.5, y_max + 0.5)
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting image]