# PyPlot: color scatter plot data based on target value

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a data frame with 2 dimensions. i.e.

```py
data = [[  7.08535569   5.20423916]
 [ -6.12292297  -9.79831639]
 [ -0.14405156   0.02112219]
 ...
 [ -2.93838878   2.4744518 ]
 [  8.07134259 -10.8165695 ]
 [  5.14161567   2.68737039]]
```

I also have a target value for each index i.e.

```py
target = [-1, 1, 1, -1 ... -1, 1, -1, -1]
```

What is the easiest way to use PyPlot to color code the points based on their target value?

Currently I have

```py
X = data[:,0]
y = data[:,1]

plt.plot(X, y, 'ro')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `scatter`, which accepts additional arguments for color map:

```
...

data = [[  7.08535569   5.20423916]
 [ -6.12292297  -9.79831639]
 [ -0.14405156   0.02112219]
 ...
 [ -2.93838878   2.4744518 ]
 [  8.07134259 -10.8165695 ]
 [  5.14161567   2.68737039]]

...

plt.scatter(x, y, c=target, s=500, cmap='gray')
plt.show()

...
```

References:

[Matplotlib scatterplot; colour as a function of a third variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8202605/matplotlib-scatterplot-colour-as-a-function-of-a-third-variable)

Comment: The data I have is a scatter plot, not a line graph like the SO post you linked. Im very new at mpl, are these treated the same?

Comment: @SwimMaster I've updated my answer for scatter plot